# How to get linkedin profile follower count

Tags: linkedin-api

Hi guys i want the follower count from linkedin profile so I am using the linkedin rest api "https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api" but unable to get data, instead showing the following error.

```
{
"errorCode": 0,
"message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
"requestId": "J4YFQZZ4E5",
"status": 401,
"timestamp": 1469104044650
}
```

Could you guys tell me what is the correct way to use the api so that to get the "Follower count"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have generated the access token first then using that token I am authenticating the user.

Then I have used linkedin rest api (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) to get the follower count.